# erlang shell can not interprete control characters

Tags: linux, shell, erlang, tty

i have a question of Erlang Shell about display.
i use Xshell to connect to Linux server, the TERM variable and the terminal type of Xshell are both set to 'xterm-256color'.
But when i go into Erlang Shell, i input 'ctrl-H', 'ctrl-A' and some other control characters, erlang shell has a weird display like:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> hello^H^A
```

thus, i can not input ctrl-g to call erlang shell utils.
but when i am back to bash, it is ok to use ctrl-h to delete previous character and ctrl-a to go to head of line, why erlang shell behaves this way.
is there something i did not setup right? related to stty?
/br
ruan

Comment: i just can not use ctrl-a ctrl-e in erlang shell, and these emacs-like shortcuts can not be understood properly. something wrong with erlang or something wrong with shell?

Comment: How do you start `erl`? Any special parameters?

Comment: @evnu, no any special parameters

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour with putty (or any other SSH client)?